# Can a C++ TCP socket on a Ubuntu server only get as many clients as the limit for open file descriptors?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, ubuntu, file-descriptor

I'm not sure if the question makes proper sense.

I am creating a game, and writing its server in C++ using socket programming. I would like to know, can the TCP socket only have as many active clients connected to it at a time as the number of open file descriptor limit in Ubuntu?

Comment: Some handy reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157351/why-are-tcp-ip-sockets-considered-open-files

Comment: The simple answer is yes. Each active connection uses a file descriptor.